# How to fix this MySql syntax error in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, netbeans

I'm making data installing form and trying to save those data in db. 
And I'm getting this given below error. 
**error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, total) VALUES ('MM20', '520.00' , 'S.Hashan' ,'522.00' , 'hgASKCHkbzmbk' ' at line 1** 

Actually I'm sending six records. 'MM20', '520.00' , 'S.Hashan' ,'522.00' , 'hgASKCHkbzmbk' ,'5200.00' 
But only five is sending as the error showing. Given below is my source code. Please help me.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if ($con) {
$db = mysql_select_db('mobile', $con);
} else {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

 if (array_key_exists('save_data', $_POST)) {

 $model_no = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['model_no']);
 $service_fee = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['service_fee']);
 $sp_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sp_name']);
 $sp_price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sp_price']);
 $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
 $total = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['total']);

 $query ="INSERT INTO mobile_rep (model_no, service_fee, sp_name, sp_price, desc,      total)
 VALUES ('{$model_no}', '{$service_fee}' , '{$sp_name}' ,'{$sp_price}' , '{$desc}' ,    '{$total}')";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
    echo "1 record added";
} else {
    echo "error";
    echo '<br/>'.  mysql_error();
}    
  }
      mysql_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: `desc` is a reserve keyword so you need to escape it. eg. `..,sp_name, sp_price,\`desc\`, ...`

Comment: It would be better if you change this name desc for describe or whatever.

Comment: @今草顿웃  you should post as an answer.

Comment: If this is just for testing purposes then okay but otherwise I highly suggest moving from mysql_* to either PDO which is more preferable or mysqli_*.

Comment: :D @今 草 顿 웃 and @Jorge Campos  thanks guys. Its working. you know I always cought up with these key words. :(

Comment: @attis Sorry. Can you explain bit what you are saying..

Comment: @Dilini he are saying that the mysql* comands are deprecated, you should consider in using the newer versions of mysql interact with php which is PDO or mysqli* functions. Give it a little research.

Comment: @AttisBarros I will do it. Thanks.. :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos thank you for explaning my suggestion in details.

Comment: MySQL is deprecated.  If you do not want that much of a change, you can use procedural MySQLi, which is very syntactically similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify Your Query :

```
$query ="INSERT INTO mobile_rep (`model_no`, `service_fee`, `sp_name`, `sp_price`, `desc`,      `total`) VALUES ('{$model_no}', '{$service_fee}' , '{$sp_name}' ,'{$sp_price}' , '{$desc}' ,    '{$total}')";
```

DESC is Reserved word in MySQL. Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them.

Answer (score 0):

basically,this is on behalf of @今 草 顿 웃 so that the question can be closed.

desc is a reserve keyword so you need to escape it. eg. ..,sp_name, sp_price,`desc`, ...

Comment: @Dilini I thought of posting it so that you have an answer to accept but seems like you have already done that..;)